# Element.children.item() method

Tags: javascript, methods, parameter-passing

I was searching for the easiest way to access an element child, I found a method called Item() that takes the index and returns the child node, but I tried to pass a class name into it, and it worked successfully and returned the element node that I need

`console.log(this.elementNode.children.item('.close'));` Its result
[image]

My question is: is this way good practice or is it a js bug? Can I depend on it or not?

Comment: Is the button the first child in the node? I just tested it on chrome and it'll return the first child if the argument is not a number

Comment: yeah, it still returns the first element :)

Comment: According to the [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-htmlcollection-item), the argument is supposed to be an integer >= 0 (`unsigned long` in the engine) so I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: yeah, it should return an error